# Merge fastq.gz files with same name in different localizations in Google-Cloud

Tags: bash, merge, google-cloud-functions

I would like to merge several fastq.gz files with the same name in different folders in the Google-Cloud. I have a total of 15 patients. Each patient has paired-end data "R1" and "R2". Each R1 and R2 are divided into 4 files. The size of each file is approximately 28 GB.

My goal is to merge the 4 files to obtain the complete fastq.gz R1 and R2 files for each patient.

I have never worked with Google-Cloud before.

Here is how the folders and the files are in the bucket (example with 2 patients):

```
gs://bucketID
     /folder1
         /folder001
             Patient1_R1.fastq.gz
             Patient1_R2.fastq.gz
         /folder002
             Patient2_R1.fastq.gz
             Patient2_R2.fastq.gz
etc.

     /folder2
         /folder003
             Patient1_R1.fastq.gz
             Patient1_R2.fastq.gz
         /folder004
             Patient2_R1.fastq.gz
             Patient2_R2.fastq.gz
etc.

     /folder3
         /folder005
             Patient1_R1.fastq.gz
             Patient1_R2.fastq.gz
         /folder006
             Patient2_R1.fastq.gz
             Patient2_R2.fastq.gz
etc.

     /folder4
         /folder007
             Patient1_R1.fastq.gz
             Patient1_R2.fastq.gz
         /folder008
             Patient2_R1.fastq.gz
             Patient2_R2.fastq.gz
etc.
```

I want to make a script that targets fastq.gz files with the same name in different folders, then merge them. However, I have no idea how to do this on Google-Cloud.

Here is the same example with colors (I want to concatenate files with the same color):

[Example with colors](http://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=19/42/c9j7.jpg)

Here's how I see the bash script:

```
bucket="bucketID"
dir1=$bucket/"folder1"
dir2=$bucket/"folder2"
dir3=$bucket/"folder3"
dir4=$bucket/"folder4"
destdir=$bucket/"destdir"

participants = (Patient1
                Patient2
               )

for i in ${participants[*]};
do
    zcat dir1/.../$i/_R1.fastq.gz dir2/.../$i/_R1.fastq.gz dir3/.../$i/_R1.fastq.gz dir4/.../$i/_R1.fastq.gz | gzip >$destdir/"merged_"$i/_R1.fastq.gz
    zcat dir1/.../$i/_R2.fastq.gz dir2/.../$i/_R2.fastq.gz dir3/.../$i/_R2.fastq.gz dir4/.../$i/_R2.fastq.gz | gzip >$destdir/"merged_"$i/_R2.fastq.gz

done
```

Should I use "gsutil compose" instead to merge?

At the end, I would like to have only two files R1 and R2 for each patient: merged_patient#_R1.fastq.gz and merged_patient#_R2.fastq.gz.

In the example I gave above, it would give 4 files:

```
merged_Patient1_R1.fastq.gz
merged_Patient1_R2.fastq.gz
merged_Patient2_R1.fastq.gz
merged_Patient2_R2.fastq.gz
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO :) Please take some time when posting a question. Make it look good, make it as clear as possible, and also give your best to format it well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use the following command in order to concatenate your files:

```
gsutil compose gs://bucket/obj1 [gs://bucket/obj2 ...] gs://bucket/composite
```

You can check the documentation in [this link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/compose).

I've tried to do a simple bash script by using the "gsutil compose" command with fastq.gz files, and it was working fine for me.

The compose command creates a new object whose content is the concatenation of a given sequence of source objects **under the same bucket**.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi eespinola,

Thank you for your answer. 

I agree I have to use the command "gsutil compose" to concatenate the file.

However what I want to know is how I can target the files with the same name in different folders. 

If you look at this link:
[example image with colors](http://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=19/42/c9j7.jpg)

I want to merge the files with the same color. I would like to use a script for this (I don't want to do it manually for each patient).

How can I do this with a bash script ?

Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the solution with gsutil compose :

```sh
declare -a participantsArray=("Patient1"
                              "Patient2"
                             )
bucket="bucketID"
dir1=$bucket/"folder1"
dir2=$bucket/"folder2"
dir3=$bucket/"folder3"
dir4=$bucket/"folder4"
destdir=$bucket/"destdir"

for i in ${participantsArray[@]};
do
    fileR1="${i}_R1.fastq.gz"
    fileR2="${i}_R2.fastq.gz"

    gsutil compose "${dir1}/*/${fileR1}" "${dir2}/*/${fileR1}" "${dir3}/*/${fileR1}" "${dir4}/*/${fileR1}" "${destdir}/merged_${fileR1}"
    gsutil compose "${dir1}/*/${fileR2}" "${dir2}/*/${fileR2}" "${dir3}/*/${fileR2}" "${dir4}/*/${fileR2}" "${destdir}/merged_${fileR2}"

done
```

As you said the solution was not difficult to find.

Thank you again!